# How to position a div in accordance to another div's margin?

Tags: html, css

I have got two divs.

```
<div class="header"></div>

<div class="container">
<p>This is the container.</p>
</div>
```

And this is the css code.

```
.header{
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    position:fixed;
    background-color:#eee;
}
.container{
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top:100px;
    margin-bottom:100px;
}
```

Why does the header come down, even though I have put a margin top on the container? Can someone suggest me a way to have a fixed header along with the rest of the stuff in container just like any other usual page?

Comment: `position:fixed` takes the header out of the document flow, thus the margin has no idea it is there. To learn more about layouts in CSS, check out [this useful site](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: Make us a fiddle or codepen, so we get the whole picture of your issue ? somehow your css seems coherent but .... you have a problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `top:0` in the header css. http://jsfiddle.net/Nh3Tf/

Comment: left is missing too :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `top:0;` and `left: 0;`

```
.header{
width:100%;
height:100px;
position:fixed;
background-color:#eee;
top: 0;
left: 0;

}
```

Have a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sjadC/2/)

Comment: left is missing too :)